# Would this be correct to prove that two ideals are equal?

Tags: polynomials, ideals, groebner-basis

Given that reduced Gröbner bases are unique for any given ideal and any monomial ordering, would it be correct to prove that two given ideals, $I_1$ and $I_2$, are equal following this process?

1. Choose a polynomial ordering.
2. Calculate the reduced Gröbner base of $I_1$ (using the selected ordering)
3. Calculate the reduced Gröbner base of $I_2$ (using the selected ordering)

If both results match, $I_1$ is equal to $I_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and you don't even need the reduced property to prove that $I_1=I_2$. Let $G_1$ be any Gröbner basis for $I_1$. Let $G_2$ be any Gröbner basis for $I_2$. If $G_1=G_2$, then $I_1=\langle G_1\rangle=\langle G_2\rangle=I_2$. The point is that two ideals with the same generating set must be equal.

However, the power of *reduced* Gröbner bases comes in as follows: if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are *reduced* and $G_1\not=G_2$, then $I_1\not= I_2$. This is just because the reduced Gröbner basis for any ideal is unique (with respect to a given monomial order).

So if your goal is to algorithmically determine if two ideals are equal *or not*, then yes, you can compute reduced Gröbner bases to detect this.